# Using camera to save data on background

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to run a service which will save data from the device's existing camera, at real-time, upon taking a picture. I want to do so without opening an Activity or creating my own Camera app.

My app is working in the background. the user is supposed to take pictures normally , in the default Camera app, without disturbance.

Does anyone have an idea how to do so?

Or point me on some direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To takePicture you have to call Camera.startPreview() first. To call Camera.startPreview() you have to call Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Holder) before. To set priview you have to get Holder from SurfaceView. So anyway you must have SurfaceView in your layout. And sure you must have layout (in other words Activity).

Comment: I've tried to clarify my question. please check again. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correction properly. Do you want to get pictures that user makes in default app?

Comment: Yes. mostly I'm interested in the filename and date, using it in a database. The picture itself is not as important.

Comment: You can use ContentObserver to receive any changes in gallery (photos from camera are inputed there in Camera folder)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to launch an activity which set's the camera preview up and then start the service? After the service is running and has a hard-ref to the camera just simulate a home button press:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HOME);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(i);
```

This way your activity just get's in the background but is still alive (until Android claims for more memory).